# Present Perfect Vs. Simple Past in my sentence

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, past-simple, verb-usage

Which one should I use?

> I've read The Little Prince, Chapter XVIV. **It has been** pretty good - **It has been** about [...]

Or

> I've read the Little Prince, chapter XVIV. **It was** pretty good - **It was** about [...]

I know that we use Present perfect when the is not specific. But at least for me, it sounds strange saying "it has been" as opposed to "it was". Is it right?

For me, the past Simple sentence is "better" (even though it's not "grammatically" correct)

Comment: Why do you think the past simple is "better but ungrammatical" (a self-contradictory remark)? What does the past simple mean there, and what about the present perfect?

Comment: I'm not sure, but usually it is said _I've read Chapter X of The Little Prince,_  isn't it?

Comment: Hm. I think *has been* (when *be* is not itself an auxiliary, as in *has been cooked*) applies to a continuing state (*Bob has been here for an hour*), not a completed state; so I'd say a book *has been* good only if I have not finished reading it.

Answer (score 1):

If you opine something that is 'all-time true,' you *generally* use the base verb.

> I have read The Little Prince, Chapter XVIV. It ***is*** pretty good; it ***is*** about ...

This is because what you are stating *remains* correct. It's not *momentary.*

Something like...

> I've watched *Titanic,* it ***is*** a good movie.

It does not matter whether the movie was released decades back. Your opinion stands true since then.

On the other hand, if you use *has/have been,* it immediately denotes the time range - from that point till now. Such usage is unusual in *this context.*

Using *was* is true if the event was *momentary.*

> The movie *was* in Eastman color [which means, *now* it has been remastered].